# label not moving with Vuejs2 + Materializejs

Tags: vuejs2, materialize

I have a problem with the label of a text input with materializejs + vuejs

the label does not move up if I change the value of the input field *with* vue (it behaves correctly if I change manually the input)

[image]

a simple (not elegant) code showing that is (also on [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/carlobellettini/gb8jsL46/1/)):

- correct expected behavior by editing the field manually
- not correct behavior by clicking on the last div (starting from an empty field): it changes the value of the input without moving the label

**html**

```
<div id=app>
  <div class="input-field ">
    <input type="text" v-model="value" id="field">
    <label for="field">Field</label>
  </div>

  <div @click="value='newValue'">
    clickOnMe
  </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    value: ''
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Prefilling Text Inputs section](http://materializecss.com/forms.html), seems there's a patch function that needs to be applied

```html
<div @click="clickMe">
```

```js
methods: {
  clickMe() {
    this.value = 'newValue';
    $(document).ready(function() {
        Materialize.updateTextFields();
    });     
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you 

the `active` class does not work (firs suggestion in the link) 
but the `updateTextField` trick worked well...

I hope however that they will solve that in a cleaner way in the future versions

Comment: Indeed! I also tried a Vue computed setter, but that did not work.

Comment: Thanks for providing the fiddle, makes it really easy to get to a working solution.